# Counting duplicates interleaved with different values in a pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

Here is a very simplified version of my data:

```
    ╔═════════╤═══════════╗
    ║ user_id │ module_id ║
    ╠═════════╪═══════════╣
    ║ 1       │ 1         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 1       │ 1         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 1       │ 2         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 1       │ 1         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 1         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 1         ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         ║
    ╚═════════╧═══════════╝
```

and here's the column I would like to add:

```
    ╔═════════╤═══════════╤════════════════════╗
    ║ user_id │ module_id │ repeated_module_id ║
    ╠═════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════╣
    ║ 1       │ 1         │ NaN                ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 1       │ 1         │ NaN                ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 1       │ 2         │ NaN                ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 1       │ 1         │ 1                  ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         │ NaN                ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 1         │ NaN                ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         │ 2                  ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         │ NaN                ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 1         │ 1                  ║
    ╟─────────┼───────────┼────────────────────╢
    ║ 2       │ 2         │ 2                  ║
    ╚═════════╧═══════════╧════════════════════╝
```

I.e. a module is repeated if the user has done it before, but not immediately before.

I would like a vectorised pandas way of deriving this, but I cannot see how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` on the entire frame to check both `user_id` *and* `module_id`, you shouldn't need a `groupby` + `apply`.  Then it's as simple as masking based on your initial frame.

```python
m1 = df['module_id'].ne(df['module_id'].shift())
m2 = df.duplicated(['user_id', 'module_id'])

df['module_id'].where(m1 & m2)
```

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    2.0
7    NaN
8    1.0
9    2.0
Name: module_id, dtype: float64
```

---

This should be a great deal faster than `apply`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': np.random.randint(1, 100, 10_000),
    'module_id': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10_000)
})

In [285]: %%timeit
     ...:     m1 = df['module_id'].ne(df['module_id'].shift())
     ...:     m2 = df.duplicated(['user_id', 'module_id'])
     ...:     df['module_id'].where(m1 & m2)
     ...:
2.56 ms ± 199 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [302]: %%timeit
     ...: df.loc[df.groupby('user_id')['module_id'].apply(lambda x:
     ...:         x.ne(x.shift())&x.duplicated()),'module_id']
     ...:
92.6 ms ± 1.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is less cryptic too (though that may just be my lack of pandas experience)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try :

```python
df=df.assign(repeated_module_id=df.loc[df.groupby('user_id')['module_id'].apply(lambda x:
        x.ne(x.shift())&x.duplicated()),'module_id'])
```

---

```
   user_id  module_id  repeated_module_id
0        1          1                 NaN
1        1          1                 NaN
2        1          2                 NaN
3        1          1                 1.0
4        2          2                 NaN
5        2          1                 NaN
6        2          2                 2.0
7        2          2                 NaN
8        2          1                 1.0
9        2          2                 2.0
```